# Limit sup limit inf

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

I am getting confused about the definition of $\limsup$. It's been given in the books that if $M$ is the $\limsup x_n$ then $x_n < M+\varepsilon$ except finitely many $n$ i.e. for all $n > N$ and $x_n> M-\varepsilon$ for infinitely many $n$. 
I am having problem in understanding the difference between “except finitely many $n$” & “infinitely many $n$”.

Comment: The statement ''$n$ is odd'' is true for infinitely many $n$.  The statement "$n \ge 7$" is true for all except finitely many $n$ (assuming $n$ refers to natural numbers).

Comment: There are several equivalent definitions of $\limsup$ and $\liminf$  of a sequence. It is a very good exercise to prove that the defs are indeed equivalent. That way, you see exactly what is going on. Then, play with sequences you are familiar with to see how the ideas fit together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider , for instance, the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}=\left(\dfrac1n+(-1)^n\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$. Its $\limsup$ is $1$. Now, take $\varepsilon=\dfrac12$. Then:

- the inequality $x_n<1+\varepsilon$ takes place except for finitely many $n$'s; actually, it fails only when $n=2$;
- the inequality $x_n>1-\varepsilon$ takes place for infinitely many $n$'s: it occurs when (and only when) $n$ is even.